# Printing and Writing over Bytes

Tags: c, memory, malloc, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write into a byte that I have allocated using `malloc()`. I'm really struggling with correctly printing out the bits and the values.

```
int main(){

    unsigned char *heap = (unsigned char *) malloc( 2 * sizeof(char)); //allocate two bytes

    int n= 2, i =0;
    unsigned char* byte_array = heap;

    while (i < 2) //trying to write over the first byte then print out to verify
    {   
        printf("%016X\n", heap[i]);
        heap[i] = "AAA";
        printf("%p\n", heap[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
0000000000000000
0xc7
0000000000000000
0xc7
```

Comment: What do you expect `heap[i] = "AAA"` to do? `"AAA"` isn’t an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Where to begin?  Your compiler should be warning about `heap[i] = "AAA";` — you're trying to assign a `char *` to an `unsigned char`.  That shows you've got a problem.  You're trying to print `heap[i]` as a pointer, but it isn't a pointer,  it's an `unsigned char`.  You can't afford to ignore warnings your compiler gives you — at this stage in your career, they're all errors in your code (or your understanding of the code).  Even later on, they're errors; they just won't trigger questions on SO any more.

Comment: Was there a point to keeping `byte_array` in this post?

Answer (score 0):

To understand difference between "string" and 'c' character in C. Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    /* Usual way */
    char *a = "A";
    char *b = "B";
    char *c = "C";

    printf("Address of a = 0x%x\n",a);
    printf("Address of b = 0x%x\n",b);
    printf("Address of c = 0x%x\n",c);

    /* Explicit way - Because you asked above question */
    printf("This is Base Address of String A = 0x%x\n","A");
    printf("This is Base Address of string B = 0x%x\n","B");
    printf("This is Base Address of string C = 0x%x\n","C");

    /* Now, let us print content - The usual way */
    printf("Pointer value a has %x\n",*a);
    printf("Pointer value b has %x\n",*b);
    printf("Pointer value c has %x\n",*c);

    /* The unusual way */
    printf("Value of String A  %x\n",*"A");
    printf("Value of String B  %x\n",*"B");
    printf("Value of String C  %x\n",*"C");

}
```

The above code will generate compiler warning because char * is formatted as unsigned int, but just ignore it to understand the example.

The output would look like following:

```
Address of a = 0xedfce4a
Address of b = 0xedfce4c
Address of c = 0xedfce4e
This is Base Address of String A = 0xedfce4a
This is Base Address of string B = 0xedfce4c
This is Base Address of string C = 0xedfce4e
Pointer value a has 41
Pointer value b has 42
Pointer value c has 43
Value of String A  41
Value of String B  42
Value of String C  43
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are doing some operations without really knowing the meaning:

```
while (i < 2) 
{   
    printf("%016X\n", heap[i]); // You're printing the value of heap[i] in hexadecimal that
                                // is not even setted
    heap[i] = "AAA";            // This operation has no sense, 'cause a 
                                // "char" can only contain 1 character


    printf("%p\n", heap[i]);    // You are printing a pointer, why?
    i++;
}
```

The char in C can contain only ONE character. So this has a sense:

```
 char a = 'b';
```

and if you want to have a string you need an array of char:

```
 char * a = "AAA";
```

For more read [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/)

So I would rewrite the code in this way:

```
 while (i < 2){
     printf("First: %c\n",heap[i]);
     heap[i] = 'a';
     printf("After: %c\n",heap[i]);
     i++;
 }
```